# Replacing GridView using jQuery table in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

The web application is using SQL DB connections, web services. **User needs to insert, edit, delete database records**. And Currently due to certain cosmetic features of GridView, we having issues to provide the features required by customer for a dry run demo.

**Lacking features:**

- Freezing GridView Header
- Freezing GridView Header with multiple Sub

**What holds us back:**
 - GridView and its events

And all the styling, calendars, positioning are done using CSS, js, jquery. In my opinion the web app will be even less *heavier* if we switch to js based code.
I even utilized a jquery plug-in to do the freezing of a GridView with just one header. But for sub headers - it's challenging again. This is a commercial multi-user environment, (must be responsive) application. The site will be called from third party ERP systems.

So before switching everything into jQuery, I just want to know the credibility and current and future (forseen) updates for jQuery compared to ASP.Net GridView. How would jquery will respond to call-backs, postbacks?
Please point out any critical points or insights to consider.

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick and random list of stuff that you will need to do in case of a JS solution

1. You will need to create all server side handlers for CRUD
   operations.
2. Make sure to handle ajax queries and client click
   events properly to avoid repeat inserts.
3. You can use bootstrap or
   tablesorter for the purpose of building html table which is
   responsive
4. Table sorter can also give you additional functionality
   with addons like filter, pagination, etc. [Demo for TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)
5. Make sure to protect your handler pages on the server with some sort of token mechanism if you intend to keep the site open on the internet.
6. Due to the JS solution you might end up essential with a single page application. The JS and Server handlers can get messy pretty quickly. Be careful with that.
7. Since you can set this using bootstrap and plain HTML all the fancy features you mentioned are just a CSS away ;-) [Bootstrap Examples can be found here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)
8. You mentioned that the app will be less heavier...thats correct, but it will be lighter on server side and heavier on client side. Carefully test this on mobile browsers as it can get really HEAVY to the point of freezing. Make some backup for those type of users if you care or it is a business requirement.

thats all for now...i will keep this updated

Comment: This is a big headache than to juggle with GridView for cosmetics of the page. I just wonder why in the world VS didn't have any upgrades on GridView as its one of the main components. Would it kill Microsoft to add that in...

Comment: i think with the advancement in client side frameworks and HTML5 most of the server side components are obsolete...none the less they still are helpful for rapid development and make things work.


Believe me once you move to client side data handling you will not want to go back...the performance upgrade and flexibility is just awesome.


Consider you want to write a native smartphone app for the same application...you have most of the server stuff ready (handlers can be reused as a webservice)

Comment: But quoting from you: `You will need to create all server side handlers for CRUD operations.`. So it means have to create the server side handlers. Totally with you in terms of client side improvements. Do you know how to freeze a GridView with Sub Headers? (just one part of the problem).